# CUDA image processing

Tags: image-processing, cudalink

I am having an issue with image processing involving `CUDALink`.

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CUDAQ[]

images = FileNames["*.jpg", "C:\\Users\\rwheatley\\Desktop\\All Folders\\Pics\\"];
count = 1;
Do[imagevar[count++] = Import[image], {image, images}];
Length[images]

start = SessionTime[];
For[i = 1, i < Length[images], i++, CUDAImageConvolve[imagevar[i], {{-1, -2, 3}}]]
CUDATime = SessionTime[] - start;

start1 = SessionTime[];
For[i = 1, i < Length[images], i++, ImageConvolve[imagevar[i], {{-1, -2, 3}}]]
Regular = SessionTime[] - start1;

CUDATime
Regular
```

With 34 iPhone6+ HDR photos, this always has CUDA taking longer by a factor of 4. Does anyone see what is wrong with my code?

```
In[43]:= CUDAInformation[]

Out[43]= {1 -> {"Name" -> "NVS 5200M", "Clock Rate" -> 1344000, 
  "Compute Capabilities" -> 2.1, "GPU Overlap" -> 1, 
  "Maximum Block Dimensions" -> {1024, 1024, 64}, 
  "Maximum Grid Dimensions" -> {65535, 65535, 65535}, 
  "Maximum Threads Per Block" -> 1024, "Maximum Shared Memory Per Block" -> 49152, 
  "Total Constant Memory" -> 65536, "Warp Size" -> 32, "Maximum Pitch" -> 2147483647, 
  "Maximum Registers Per Block" -> 32768, "Texture Alignment" -> 512, 
  "Multiprocessor Count" -> 2, "Core Count" -> 64, "Execution Timeout" -> 1, 
  "Integrated" -> False, "Can Map Host Memory" -> True, "Compute Mode" -> "Default", 
  "Texture1D Width" -> 65536, "Texture2D Width" -> 65536, "Texture2D Height" -> 65535, 
  "Texture3D Width" -> 2048, "Texture3D Height" -> 2048, "Texture3D Depth" -> 2048, 
  "Texture2D Array Width" -> 16384, "Texture2D Array Height" -> 16384,  
  "Texture2D Array Slices" -> 2048, "Surface Alignment" -> 512, 
  "Concurrent Kernels" -> True, "ECC Enabled" -> False, "TCC Enabled" -> False, 
  "Total Memory" -> 1073741824}}
```

Thanks to @MarcoB I have modified my code to be more Mathematica-Like as follows:
    ClearAll["Global`*"]
    Needs["CUDALink`"]
    CUDAQ[]

```
images = FileNames["*.jpg", "C:\\Users\\rwheatley\\Desktop\\All Folders\\Pics\\"];
imagevar = Import /@ images;

Clear[images]
MemoryInUse[]

CUDAImageConvolve[#, {{-1, -2, 3}}] & /@ imagevar; // AbsoluteTiming
ImageConvolve[#, {{-1, -2, 3}}] & /@ imagevar;  // AbsoluteTiming
```

The issue still remains for CUDA being slower, though. I have even tried the following to no avail:

```
mem = CUDAMemoryLoad[#] & /@ imagevar;

CUDAImageConvolve[#, {{-1, -2, 3}}] & /@ mem; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Hello, I was just about to modify my post but I saw your comment. I can get CUDAMemoryLoad and CUDAMemoryAllocate to work on one image but now I am having problems with how to do that with lists.

CUDAMemoryLoad@ImageData[image];
CUDAMemoryAllocate[Real, Dimensions@ImageData[image]];
CUDAImageConvolve[image, {{-1, -2, 3}}]

Question is how to do that with lists as MarcoB suggested. I have tried modifying the code

Comment: @Richard Reading the CUDALink manual seems to indicate that the memory management happens automatically behind the scenes, i.e. the data is moved from host to device memory automatically, and back. See [this section of the Memory CUDALink tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/tutorial/Memory.html#841606779). In fact, the tutorial states that "Using the memory manager is an optimization technique. As a rule of thumb, the user should get the CUDA program to work before dabbling with memory." Unfortunately, though, I can't test CUDA stuff directly for lack of hardware.

Comment: @andre Since I am using imagevar as a list of images now, I changed the code to:

`images = FileNames["*.jpg", "C:\\Users\\rwheatley\\Desktop\\All Folders\\Pics\\"];`
`imagevar = Import /@ images;`
`Union[ImageType /@ imagevar]`
`Union[ImageColorSpace /@ imagevar]`
`Union[ImageDimensions /@ imagevar]`

{"Byte"}

{"RGB"}

{{369, 100}, {381, 325}, {390, 231}, {400, 400}, {620, 620}, {678, 
  592}, {850, 540}, {1200, 1199}, {1836, 3264}, {2448, 3264}, {3264, 
  2448}}

Comment: @andre, thank you for assisting me, btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CUDAImageConvolve` is slow due to memory tranfert between the different memories (CPU and GPU). One can decompose the action of `CUDAImageConvolve` in 6 phases and get de timing of each phase.

Here are the results, compared with the CPU `ImageConvolve` and the straight `CUDAImageConvolve` :

[image]

One can see that the convolution alone takes only 16 mS.

This information can be usefull if you have a sequence of operations to do without leaving the GPU memory.

**Here is the code :**

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CUDAQ[]

imagevar = ExampleData /@ {{"TestImage","House2"},
{"TestImage","Lena"},{"TestImage","Mandrill"}}


AbsoluteTiming[ImageConvolve[#, {{-1, -2, 3}}]& /@ imagevar]
AbsoluteTiming[CUDAImageConvolve[#, {{-1, -2, 3}}]& /@ imagevar]
```

> [image]

Initialization :

```
AbsoluteTiming[memList=CUDAMemoryLoad[ImageData[#]]& /@ imagevar;]
AbsoluteTiming[CUDAMemoryCopyToDevice /@ memList;]
(*CUDAMemoryInformation[memList[[1]]]*)
AbsoluteTiming[outMemList=CUDAMemoryAllocate["Double",Append[ImageDimensions[#],3]]& /@ imagevar;]
```

> {0.0467458, Null}
>   {0.0143745, Null}
>   {0.000671206, Null}

convolution :

```
AbsoluteTiming[(CUDAImageConvolve[#[[1]], {{-1, -2, 3}},"OutputMemory"-> #[[2]]])& /@ Transpose[{memList,outMemList}];]
```

> {0.0151647, Null}

restitution :

```
AbsoluteTiming[Image[CUDAMemoryGet[#]]& /@ outMemList]
AbsoluteTiming[CUDAMemoryUnload /@ Flatten[{memList,outMemList}];]
```

> [image]

NOTE :

`CUDAMemoryLoad[ImageData[#]]& /@ imagevar`is used instead of `CUDAMemoryLoad /@ imagevar` because `CUDAMemoryLoad[image]` create a 2D array of {Byte,Byte,Byte} even if the image is a 2D array of {Float,Float,Float}. The consequence is that the convolution creates a overflow on the Bytes, and the resulting image is then :

[image]

Comment: Very nice analysis!

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I also only have a 1GB NVIDIA card. I am going to start working on smaller subsets and possibly divide up the tasks so that I am not loading all images to the GPU at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

This is an extended comment on code style, rather than on your problem. Unfortunately I don't have a CUDA-capable card, so I can't test your actual issue.

Generally speaking, however, you will want to try and get away from procedural loops when writing *Mathematica* code:

- [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in *Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/27951)
- [Why should I avoid the For loop in *Mathematica*?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/27951)

For instance in your code, instead of:

```
Do[imagevar[count++] = Import[image], {image, images}];
```

you could use:

```
imagevar = Import/@images;
```

Note that this makes `imagevar` a *list*, rather than an indexed variable, but that will actually be helpful in this case, since you can carry out "vector" operations on lists quickly and cleanly. See e.g. [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), which is used above in its "shortcut" (infix) form `/@`.

Similarly, now that `imagevar` is a list, your code

```
For[i = 1, i < Length[images], i++, CUDAImageConvolve[imagevar[i], {{-1, -2, 3}}]]
```

can be converted to the following:

```
CUDAImageConvolve[#, {{-1, -2, 3}}]& /@ imagevar;
```

If you want more information on using pure functions (i.e. the `#` and `&` expressions), take a look at [How to | Work with Pure Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html).

Timing might also be best done using [`AbsoluteTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html); see this section of the [Date and Time Functions Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DateAndTimeFunctions.html#28423). For instance, the following will directly return the time it took to carry out one instance of that operation:

```
AbsoluteTiming[CUDAImageConvolve[#, {{-1, -2, 3}}]& /@ imagevar;]
```

In this context, you might also be interested in [`RepeatedTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html) for more accurate timing results.

Similarly with the last bit, to give you timing of the non-CUDA operation:

```
AbsoluteTiming[ImageConvolve[#, {{-1, -2, 3}}]& /@ imagevar;]
```

Comment: MarcoB, thank you for the Mathematica help. I wasn't thinking in terms of how to optimize the Mathematica code but the AbsoluteTiming command helped get a more accurate timing which does help me achieve a better result.

I do get slightly better timing when I replace my code with yours but I still get 3-4 times the period when I use CUDA instead of the regular command.